# Is there any connection between logarithmic algebraic geometry and the "field with one element"?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, monoid

Monoid schemes (a.k.a. $\frak M$-schemes) have been introduced by Deitmar as a possible approach to geometry over the field with one element. These build upon monoids as the basic building blocks for algebraic geometry in the place of rings. There's also a variant of Connes--Consani which uses pointed monoids instead of monoids, giving so-called $\frak Mo$-schemes. Connes--Consani's framework is in a sense more general than Deitmar's, as the latter only gives toric schemes.

On the other side, logarithmic schemes (a.k.a. log schemes) are a notion developed with a view to smoothness problems, especially in the theory of moduli, roughly allowing "logarithmic singularities" to be considered as smooth. One defines a log structure on a scheme $X$ to be a sheaf of commutative unpointed monoids $\mathscr{M}$ on $X$ together with a homomorphism of sheaves of monoids $\alpha\colon\mathscr{M}\to\mathscr{O}_X$ such that $\alpha^{-1}(\mathscr{O}^\times_X)\cong\mathscr{O}^\times_X$.

Since monoids, and even monoid schemes (see [Ogus's CUP book, Part II, Section 1.2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-logarithmic-algebraic-geometry/70AF7196462F4CEC018E2DABA49475F6)) appear prominently in both theories, it is natural to ask how the two interact with each other. In particular, from the above we see that a log structure on a scheme $X$ may be thought of as a morphism of $\frak M$-schemes $\alpha$ from $(X,\mathscr{M})$ to $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ such that $\alpha^{-1}(\mathscr{O}^\times_X)\cong\mathscr{O}^\times_X$.

**What is the precise connection/motivation, besides this superficial similarity, between the two theories?**

Furthermore, in the case of geometry over the field with one element, it is beneficial to consider not monoids, but *pointed* monoids, passing from $\frak M$-schemes to $\frak Mo$-schemes.

**Is it useful to work with log structures carrying sheaves of pointed commutative monoids instead of sheaves of unpointed commutative monoids?**

---

**Edit.** Ogus himself mentions $\bf F_1$ in a non-trivial way twice in his book, first on page 192:

[image]

and then on page 213:

[image]

Comment: The simplest example of log schemes are toric varieties, and I think there is a fairly well-recorded notion of toric varieties as being ‘defined over $\mathbb{F}_1$’, isn’t there?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, definitely. In fact, too much: Deitmar's work gives essentially only toric varieties, and this is an inconvenient point of the theory. On the other hand, Connes--Consani's $M_0$-schemes allow for slightly more general objects, and this is a point where passing from monoids to pointed monoids is useful. Is there something similar in this direction (replacing monoids by pointed ones) in log geometry?

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402828/what-is-the-precise-connection-between-logarithmic-algebraic-geometry-and-the-fi)